# WCF Data Services type conversion

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have a custom ValueObject type that looks like this:

```
public class Token
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a class that I want to expose over OData that looks like this:

```
[DataServiceKey("Name")]
public class Record
{
   public Token Token { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to supply a custom formatter/serializer/converter that converts my Token type into a primitive string.

I do NOT want to turn Token into an Entity just for the sake of making it work with WCF.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Token doesn't need to be an entity - it can be a complex type with the string ID.  I don't think there is a way to have a type serialized as another type... is there anything wrong with using it as a complex?

Comment: As Ian pointed out the Token doesn't need to be an entity. Although you might need to rename the Id property to something else, otherwise the heuristics kick in and assume it is an entity. There's currently no way to specify a custom serialization format for pieces of the payload in WCF DS.

Comment: This is a generalized example.  I wanted to take an object model on the server and flatten it to be compatible with an existing OData schema.  I ended up flattening the entities on the server side instead.